# Bluebird promise.all not respecting result order

Tags: node.js, promise, bluebird

I'm using latest stable bluebird:

```
"bluebird": "~3.4.0",
```

And with the following code:

```
Promise.all([ParticipantsService.retrieveActiveParticipantsFromTheLocalDb(),
    EventService.retrieveActiveEventsFromTheLocalDb(),
    HeatService.retrieveActiveHeatsFromTheLocalDb()]).then(
    function (results) {
        var namedResults = {participants: results[0], events: results[1], heats: results[2]};
        return res.render('runners/runners', namedResults);
    }).catch(
    function (err) {
        winston.error('Failed to retrieve participants and or event details', err);
        return res.send(err);
    });
```

I would expect namedResults to ALWAYS have the correct order of elements matching the order in which the array of promises have been made but that is not true! I have a different order every time.

I was assuming this because it is what it says on bluebird's documentation: http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.all.html 
 Unless I'm reading this wrong...

Can anyone help?

Thanks

Comment: In my experience with bluebird, is does respect the order. Check out this JSBin http://jsbin.com/sutemogilu/edit?js,console - It works perfectly. Can you share your  `retrieveActiveParticipantsFromTheLocalDb` function and the other two? Maybe it's something about them. BTW you can use the `spread` method instead of `then` in `Promise.all` and skip the `nameResult`, you can see it commented out in the JSBin too.

Comment: So to be clear: do you mean that `participants`, `events` and `heats` in `namedResult` are getting incorrect values?

Comment: How can I reproduce this?

Comment: `namedResults` is a js plain object, therefore orderless. `results` is an array and will have the order [participants, events, heats].

Comment: can you put the wrong result into the question, and what would you expect?

Comment: So the problem results is that it did have random places for the events, heats and participants ie: first run would produce: results[0] >> events, results[1] >> participants, results[2] >> heats and second run results[0] >> participants, resutls[1] >> heats and results[2] >> events

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use bluebird's Promise.props() for this:

```
Promise.props({
  participants: ParticipantsService.retrieveActiveParticipantsFromTheLocalDb(),
  events: EventService.retrieveActiveEventsFromTheLocalDb(),
  heats: HeatService.retrieveActiveHeatsFromTheLocalDb()
}).then(res.render.bind(res, 'runners/runners'))
```

Comment: Just read this reply I will try it as soon as I can but the docs sound promising! Thanks!